# Minimum Dist Between 2 Elements in an given array

Tags: c, arrays, optimization, distance

In a contest, they asked to write a C function which returns the minimum distance between X and Y in the given array, where X and Y are elements of the array Provided X AND Y ARE Distinct.

If have written a piece of code, but that code runs into many `if`'s and `else`'s,

My code (Has  Some Bugs):

```
 int getMinXYDist(int arr[],int n,int x,int y){
         int i,flag = 0,ele = -1 ,dist = 0;
         int minDist = 1000; // SETTING minDist TO MAX VALUE.
         for( i = 0 ; i< n; i++)
          if(arr[i] == x || arr[i] == y){
           if(flag == 0){
            flag = 1;
            ele = arr[i]==x?x:y;
            dist = 0;
          }
        else{
          if(ele == x ){
           if(arr[i] == y){
                minDist = dist < minDist ? dist : minDist;
                dist = 0;
                ele = y;
           }
           else //if(arr[i] == x){
               dist = 0;
          }
          else { //if(ele == y)
              if(arr[i] == x){
                minDist = dist < minDist ? dist : minDist;
                dist = 0;
                ele = x;
           }
          }

          }
        }
          else {
              if(flag == 1)
            dist++;
          }

   return minDist;
}

 void main(){
      int arr = {6,1,5,1,8,6,3,4};
      printf("\n%d" ,getMinXYDist(arr,sizeof(arr)/sizeof(int),6,5) ); //Must return 2.
 }
```

Could Any one suggest a smarter way [ Just as in O(n) time complexity ]  of calculating the distance?

Comment: could the distance be negative? or absolute value?

Comment: @gongzhitaao no distance cannot be negative.

Comment: @gongzhitaao if my array is 6 1 5 8 2 8 4 6, dist between  1 and 6 , and 6 and 1 are same. And the distance is 1.

Comment: Did you not say your numbers have to be distinct?

Comment: Trying to understand the problem: Will `abs( indexOf( X ) - indexOf( Y ) )`, where `indexOf()` is a simple linear search function, provide the correct the answer?

Comment: @AdrianJandl yes X and Y have to be distinct.

Comment: @Arun saha But indexOf(X) and indexOf(y) must be as closer as possible.

Comment: @EAGER_STUDENT You mentioned: `6 1 5 8 2 8 4 6` which has 2 6's.
However, Arun Saha's answer should work for your problem.

Comment: @Adrian ya the arr can contain any no of repetitions. only x and y must be distinct.

Comment: +1 Thanks, now I think I understand the problem, good one, I have a solution in mind, I will try to write it up.

Answer (score 1):

If x or y is found, record the index it was found at. Once both have been found, each time you find either, compute distance to the last index containing the other value. Update the minimum value if the distance is lower than the previous minimum.

```
int getMinXYDist(int arr[],int n,int x,int y)
{
    int i, indexX, indexY;
    int foundX = 0;
    int foundY = 0;
    int curDist;
    int minDist = n;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (arr[i] == x)
        {
            foundX = 1;
            indexX = i;
            if (foundX && foundY)
            {
                curDist = indexX - indexY;
                if (curDist < minDist)
                {
                    minDist = curDist;
                }
            }
        }
        else if (arr[i] == y)
        {
            foundY = 1;
            indexY = i;
            if (foundX && foundY)
            {
                curDist = indexY - indexX;
                if (curDist < minDist)
                {
                    minDist = curDist;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return minDist;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, I think OP's solution is already optimum, the lower bound for this algorithm is `n` steps, i.e., done in one iteration.

```
// if -1 is returned, then none of x and y are in the array
// if n is returned, then one of x and y is not in the array
// otherwise, mindist(x, y) is returned.
int test(int v[], int n, int x, int y)
{
    int flag = -1;
    int i, a = -1, b = -1, dist = n;
    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        if (v[i] == x) {
            flag = 0;
            a = i;
            break;
        } else if (v[i] == y) {
            flag = 1;
            b = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (flag < 0) return -1; // x and y are both not in array;

    for (++i; i < n; ++i) {
        if (v[i] == x) {
            if (0 == flag) a = i;
            else {
                flag = 0;
                if (i - b < dist) dist = i - b;
                a = i;
            }
        } else if (v[i] == y) {
            if (1 == flag) b = i;
            else {
                flag = 1;
                if (i - a < dist) dist = i - a;
                b = i;
            }
        }
    }

    return dist;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int minDistance ( int arr[], int n, int x, int y) {

    if(x == y) return 0;
    int index1 = -1;
    int index2 = -1;
    int minvalue = n;

    for(int i = 0 ; i < n; i++){
        if((arr[i] == x) && ((i-index2) < minvalue)){
              index1 = i;                                    
              if( index2 != -1)minvalue = i-index2;
        }else if((arr[i] == y) && ((i-index1) < minvalue)){
              index2 = i;                                    
              if( index1 != -1)minvalue = i-index1;
        }     
    }
    return minvalue;
}
```

where

- `n`: size of array.
- `x` and `y`: two input number of array.

If `minvalue` returned is `n` then `x` or `y` is not present in array.

complexity: O(n), One Pass.

Comment: n: size of array.
x and y : two input number of array.
If minvalue returned is n then x or y is not present in array.
complexity : O(n), One Pass.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Enjoy. You can use the edit link to update your question.